# How can I install dual operating system in UEFI boot method.

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, multi-boot, uefi, windows-installation

I have original UEFI windows 8.1 in my laptop. I want to install windows 7 also on the same laptop. I tried some ways but it was failure and got succeeded when I installed both legacy operating systems.Is it possible..? someone can help me..?

Comment: Only 64-bit Windows 7 supported UEFI mode.

Comment: so is it possible to install windows 7 64 bit UEFI and windows 8.1 UEFI as dual boot...?

Comment: It is absolutely possible

Comment: how is it possible can you explain the steps for me it will be a big help for me...

Comment: How you dual-boot Windows 7 and Windows 8 has been documented before.  You simply install both operating systems on a HDD with multiple unallocated partitions (2).  You will want to install Windows 8 on the first unallocated partition and Windows 7 on the second